# interpolation in href attribute of button

Tags: angular

I am trying to use href in a button element; when i try `href="#collapse"`
it works fine but when I do `href="#collapse-{{option.name}}"` I get this error

> Can't bind to 'href' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

How can I add interpolation in href atribute for a button?

here is my code

```
    <div *ngFor="let option of menuOptions">
          <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-{{option.name}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <p><i-feather name="{{option.featherName}}" data-feather="option.featherName" class="sidebar-icons"></i-feather>{{option.name}}</p>
          </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[href]` is not working.

`[attr.href]` should do the job.

```
<button [attr.href]="'#collapse-' + option.name">
```

I'm not sure about an `href` on a `button` either

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```html
<button [href]="`#collapse-${option.name}`">
I'm not sure about an `href` on a `button`, but hey...
```